# Vuetify - Center v-progress-linear horizontally within v-card

Tags: css, vuejs2, progress-bar, vuetify.js

I have a custom component that is a Vuetify `v-dialog`:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="input" persistent max-width="400">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline">{{ title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
      <BaseButton
         text="Select File"
         @clicked="selectFile"
         color="accent"
         icon="cloud_upload"
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        @change="onFilePicked"
        ref="fileInput"
        class="hideme"
        multiple
      >
      {{uploadedFileNames}}
      <v-flex xs10 class="text-xs-center">
      <v-progress-linear
        height="10"
        color="accent"
        :value="uploadProgress"
      ></v-progress-linear>
      </v-flex>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="accent" flat v-if="declineText"
          @click="clicked(false)">{{ declineText }}</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="accent" flat @click="clicked(true)">{{ confirmText }}</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

With the code above, I get the following display:

[image]

What I need to do is center the progress bar horizontally within the card. I've played around with various centering classes on different elements, but I have yet to be able to get the bar to move. How can I get the progress bar centered horizontally?

Comment: show us your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you target that bar and center it?

```
 .v-progress-linear {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or it looks like you have a class to do that? `class="text-xs-center"`

If it is a flex container:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.v-progress-linear {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="v-progress-linear">
  hi
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The only thing I changed was to remove the `background-color` for `v-progress-linear`, since it's already set correctly by Vuetify.

Answer (score 1):

In the v-flex around the progress bar, change:

`<v-flex xs10 class="text-xs-center">`

to

`<v-flex xs10 class="mx-auto">`

That's a horizontal margin of "auto", around the field, which spaces the margin evenly (i.e. centers whatever is in it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-layout tag with justify-center attribute to make the thing centered vertically

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="input" persistent max-width="400">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline">{{ title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
      <v-layout justify-center > <!--THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED-->
      <BaseButton
         text="Select File"
         @clicked="selectFile"
         color="accent"
         icon="cloud_upload"
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        @change="onFilePicked"
        ref="fileInput"
        class="hideme"
        multiple
      >
      {{uploadedFileNames}}
      <v-flex xs10 class="text-xs-center">
      <v-progress-linear
        height="10"
        color="accent"
        :value="uploadProgress"
      ></v-progress-linear>
      </v-flex>
      </v-layout> <!-- Ending Tag for that -->
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="accent" flat v-if="declineText"
          @click="clicked(false)">{{ declineText }}</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="accent" flat @click="clicked(true)">{{ confirmText }}</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>

    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```